# Get HREF value by class name

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get **href value** of a specific anchor tag placed on a html page.

html tag structure

```
<a rel="nofollow" title="some title" href="http://www.this-is-what-i-need.com/just-this.html"><span><em class="buttonGo"></em>Go to this page</span></a>
```

How do I get the href value from above anchor tag using **buttonGo** class name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single line of plain Javascript will give you what you need:

```
var href = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonGo")[0].parentNode.parentNode.href;
```

But, if you aren’t sure how many times you need to use `parentNode`, you have to use a loop:

```
var anchor = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonGo")[0];
do{
anchor = anchor.parentNode;
} while(anchor.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "a");
var href = anchor.href;
```

Demo: [Solution One](http://jsfiddle.net/2mfTq/1/) (created by [Milche Patern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845310/milche-patern)) and [Solution Two](http://jsfiddle.net/2mfTq/2/)

Comment: +1, question is not taggued jQuery, only javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.buttonGo').closest('a').attr('href');
```

Without jQuery, you'll need to start with `document.getElementsByClassName('buttonGo')`, then crawl up `parentElement` until you find an `a`.

[jQuery demo](http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/2mfTq/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get attribute of tag on which you are clicking, use:

```
$(this).attr("href");
```